# loading value from database to html-select input

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I have this field saved in MYSQL database.

```
<select id="sel1" name="grpID">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="G00">option1</option>
  <option value="G01">option2</option>
  <option value="G02">option3</option>
  <option value="G03">option4</option>
</select>


$grpID=$_POST['grpID'];
mysqli_query($db_Conx, "INSERT INTO users (grpID) VALUES ('$grpID')");
```

NOW, when I load this field, I want the saved value selected in select input box.

For example, if the saved value is "G02", I want the select input field loaded like this ![selection image][1

Is there a efficient way to do this instead of selecting it with if clauses for every and each case?

Comment: A [`switch statement`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) retrieve `$grpID` from database before `<SELECT>` tag.

2) Replace html-select with:

```
<select id="sel1" name="grpID">
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="G00" <?php if($grpID=="G00") echo "selected"; ?> >option1</option>
   <option value="G01" <?php if($grpID=="G01") echo "selected"; ?> >option2</option>
   <option value="G02" <?php if($grpID=="G02") echo "selected"; ?> >option3</option>
   <option value="G03" <?php if($grpID=="G03") echo "selected"; ?> >option4</option>
</select>
```

OR you can use loop also, if `<option>` tags are too many